# Correlation between two set of variables

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to have a correlation matrice between two sets of variables. In the first set I have 9 variables, in the second one I have 24 variables. The second set of variables include the 9 variables of the first set.

For example

Here are my two set.

```
dep <- c("anxiety", "avoidance", "NEURO", "EXTRA","AGREE", "OPEN", "CONSC", "socialt", "solitaryt")

indep <-c("anxiety", "EXTRA", "NEURO", "CONSC", "OPEN", 
      "avoidance", "AGREE", "RMTQ", "RSE", "selfcontrol", "socialt",  
      "solitaryt", "riska", "stress", "socialdiversity", "networksize", "socialdiversity",
      "socialembedded", "rwa", "lonely", "SDO", "DASSD", "DASSA", "WEMWBS")
```

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: The expected outpout would be like a correlation matrice with the first set (dep) as row and the second one (indep) as column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, I found how to do it.

### I created two data frame for each set of variables:

```
df1 <- dat[, names(dat)%in% c("EXTRA", "NEURO", "CONSC", "OPEN", "AGREE", "anxiety", 
                          "avoidance", "socialt","solitaryt", "RMTQ", "RSE", "selfcontrol","riska", "stress", "socialdiversity", "networksize", "socialdiversity"
      ,"socialembedded", "rwa", "lonely", "SDO", "DASSD", "DASSA", "WEMWBS")]

df2 <- dat[,names(dat)%in% c("EXTRA", "NEURO", "CONSC", "OPEN", "AGREE", "anxiety", 
                         "avoidance", "socialt", "solitaryt")]
```

### Then I converted those df in matrix

```
A <- as.matrix(df1)
B <- as.matrix(df2)
```

### Finally we can easily correlate those data frames

```
Matrice <- cor(A, B, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```